# Dart optional parameter default values?

Tags: dart

I know you can do this for things like Strings, ints, but I'm wondering if you can set default values for more complex data types such as Maps. I've tried with the new keyword and a few other ways, but they all throw errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default parameters have to be constants. You have to define your default values with the `const` keyword.

```
m([p1 = const['a', 'b']]) => null;
```

Answer (score 5):

Default values need to be constants.

```
someFunc({someParam = const {'a': 'b'} }) => someParam;
```